# Raphael.js Animate Texts around circle

Tags: animation, svg, raphael

This fiddle will kind of explain it all:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mirodil/Ww2ud/

http://jsfiddle.net/Mirodil/Ww2ud/3/

I'm trying to animate this texts around circle. Each text has its own rotation angle degree. When i try to rotate them around circle, first text loses its rotation angle degree and second time rotate.

How can i rotate texts around circle without losing rotation angle degree?

Comment: Have a look at how this needle rotates, this may help you http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/6AMzQ/

Comment: thank you @Neil. This example helped me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Neil. This example helped me to solve my issue. Working example in the bellow link.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mirodil/XTDpF/

Comment: glad it helped you, and thanks for updating your example, this will be useful for others who find similar problem.